# Aftermarket seats

Tags: honda, safety, seat

The drivers seat in my 2011 Honda Civic causes me back and knee pain.  The rest of the vehicle is fine, so I can't justify getting another one.  I've spent much time fiddling with the adjustments, as well as trying various padding/support options.  I'm considering swapping the drivers seat entirely.

- Will any old seat from the junk yard bolt in?
- I know there are airbag sensors in the seat.  Are the sensors/connectors standard so that another make/model will interface with it?
- Aside from fit and safety, are there any other things I should be considering?

Comment: Another option you may not have considered (though potentially expensive) is an aftermarket interior shop.  You can have vehicle seats reupholstered with new material and support.

Answer (score 6):

For the first two questions : No.

Seats are made with dimensions to match the vehicle they are designed for. Finding “bolt-in” replacents needs research and, most likely, adaptor brackets or plates.

The wirng will probably not be compatible but might just work if you equate the pin- outs, but that is a big “might”...

Have you looked at aftermarket seats - they come with adaptors etc if available for your model, but as most are racing oriented you will need to test for your back...

Answer (score 4):

OEM seats, e.g. From a wrecking yard, could work... but this is a bit tricky.

Seats will definitely swap between your same model and year, so if there is an up-level trim version of the seat, that will plug right in, aside from things like one being a power seat and the other not,     They are also very likely to work for nearby model years that are the saem *generation* of the vehicle - consult Wikipedia for what year range your generation of car is in.   It will likely also work for models of other cars that share the same chassis, e.g. If Honda makes an Acura version of this particular platform.

The surest way to tell is thoroughly inspect your car for the relevant connectors -- airbag connectors look *weird* compared to others -- and then go to a "you-pull-it" type yard.

**Remember to disconnect your battery's - terminal and wait 10 minutes before doing ANY work on airbag systems.**  It is very easy to fry airbag modules if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

If you bought your car used, perhaps the previous owner(s) were oversized or damaged the seat by how they sat in it or moved around.

A replacement OEM seat, even used from a wrecking yard, might be an improvement over what you've got now.